# c++ program , sending an http get request with parameters under windows

Tags: c++, http, post, get

I searched about sending an HTTP Request using C++ or C Programming Language, and I found some libraries on GitHub and most of them are for Linux use.

in my case i just  need a little basic  piece of code that  send two parameters through a HTTP GET or POST  Request using c or c++ language under Windows .

For example : 'www.website.com/targetpage.php?param1=value&m2=value' .

Comment: [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is a small library with these features. [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) also supports network with QNetwork and QUrl

Comment: I won't call libcurl "small", but that would be my first choice as well.

Comment: i used libcurl.exe and the system('curl www.website.com/target.php?param=value') command  thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Boost Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/introduction.html).

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348344/http-client-library-for-c/37510388#37510388) for how to send an HTTP request. You can send your parameters by modifying the `req.url` variable. So, in your case it would be `/targetpage.php?param1=value&m2=value'` instead of `/`.